# Tableview not loading JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

i am creating a simple crud using Java Fx.i am beginner of javafx. while loading tableview i getting error. i attached stacktrace below. what i tried the code below.can some one help me to resolve the problem.. i am tring this last 5 days still not get a good result.

**StackTrace** i added the full StackTrace please see that below

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafxapplication10.FXMLDocumentController.table(FXMLDocumentController.java:110)
    at javafxapplication10.FXMLDocumentController.Add(FXMLDocumentController.java:154)
    ... 58 more
```

Record.class

```
public class Record {
  private final StringProperty id;
    private final StringProperty name;
    private final StringProperty address;


    public Record() {
        id = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "id");
        name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
        address = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "address");

    }

    public StringProperty idProperty() { return id; }
    public String getId() { return id.get(); }
    public void setId(String newId) { id.set(newId); }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() { return name; }
    public String getName() { return name.get(); }
    public void setName(String newName) { name.set(newName); }

    public StringProperty addressProperty() { return address; }
    public String getAddress() { return address.get(); }
    public void setAddress(String newAddress) { address.set(newAddress); }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s[id=%s, name=%s]",
            getId(), getName(), getAddress());
    }
}
```

**Table view**

```
 public void table()

      {
          Connect();
          ObservableList<Record> records = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
       try 
       {
           pst = con.prepareStatement("select id,name,address from records");  
           ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();


    {
        while (rs.next())
        {
            Record record = new Record();
            record.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            record.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            record.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
            records.add(record);
        }
    } 

    table.setItems(records);


       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().idProperty());
nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().nameProperty());
addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().addressProperty());

}
```

**Fields**

```
   @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtname;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtaddress;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtphone;


    @FXML
private TableView<Record> table;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Record, String> idColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Record, String> nameColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Record, String> addressColumn;
```

Comment: nothing obviously wrong with your snippet (at least nothing I see ;) so [mcve] please .. including boilerplate app, controller, fxml and complete error stacktrace

Comment: Your stack trace is incomplete.  Please edit your question and include all “Caused by:” sections of the stack trace.

Comment: i updated all stacktrace above

Comment: good for starters :) And now please add the other 3 parts I mentioned above ... looks like the table field is not injected properly.

Comment: can u check now

Comment: no, that's not a reproducible example - please read the referenced help page and act accordingly.

Comment: thanks  kleopatra now it working i have a doubt how to add the button on edit and delete on table view